# how to embed images in PyQt5 QScrollBar elements?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, icons, qscrollbar

I want to insert a Qscrollbar in my GUI developed in PyQt5. Customizing works fine, but I am not completely happy with the outcome. For instance, the following code (largely inspired from the example developed at [Qt Style Sheets reference](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar)) produces a horizontal Qscrollbar with custom white handle and left/right arrows):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QScrollBar, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
                        

class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollbar = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self)

        for widget in [self.scrollbar]:
            widget.valueChanged.connect(self.test)
            self.layout.addWidget(widget)

    def test(self, event):
        print(self.sender().value())


stylesheet = """
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background: #32CC99;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0 20px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background: white;
    min-width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background: #32CC99;
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background: #32CC99;
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar:left-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: white;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: none;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)  
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.resize(300, 200)
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, the arrows of the scrollbar are now replaced with ugly white squares, and the handle appears as a plain white rectangle. I would like to replace the handle with some image (png) icon, and replace the arrow squares with actual arrow images as well. I tried to modify the let-arrow and right-arrow options in a couple of ways like:

```
QScrollBar:left-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal {
    image: url(:/images/down_arrow.png)
}
```

But that does not seem to work. Trying with relative path, different options like background-image instead of image does not work either. Anyone ever succeeded in doing this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That syntax is for [Qt resources](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html), did you properly create the resource file and built it with `pyrcc`? Also, since you've set the button size to 6x6 and the border at 2, the resulting icon will only be 5x5, so even if the file has been properly loaded, you will probably not see it as it's too small.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. No, I indeed did not create a proper resource file. I would rather avoid that, if the simpler option of inserting a local file with a path is availble. is that the case? Alors, thanks for pointing the button size and border issue, I will modify this.